# Suggest a top level service worker or multiple service workers in one domain?

Tags: service-worker

If there is one domain with multiple teams and multiple web apps, what's the best suggestion of registering service worker for managing the whole site? A top level service worker with scope `/` or multiple service workers in subdomains? For cache storage in one domain is shared by all service workers, thus it's needed to control the cache with no redundancy.

Comment: Every page in the domain has its own sw config such as precache, networkfirst and so on. I tried some ways, but it's hard to split config and share cache entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the way a top level service worker with scope `/` for complex domain in production, seems more efficient.